# Copy files and services in real time from one aws instance to another

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup

I have an aws ec2 instance called **primary**. I have another ec2 instance called **secondary**. The primary instance IP is linked to domain, and contains all the hosted code and services. I want to be able to copy all the data (files/deamons/services etc) from primary to secondary on real time.

Can this be done via some service on AWS? Or if I have to write code, what kind of code/linux script etc am I looking at?

**Edits**

1. I am expecting the secondary instance to be able to instantly run the system that is being copied. As soon as a failover is detected, I will change the IP linked to the domain to this secondary machine.
2. For now the system is using database to store data, but we will be moving it to an RDS instance
3. The system is a linux machine

I looked at Load Balancer, and Auto Scaling group and EFS, but they don't solve my purpose. I looked at Elastic Bean Stalk, but it seemed like overkill for what I am trying to achieve. I can be wrong here too. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by the copy process? Is it purely a backup, or are you expecting the secondary instance to be able to instantly run the system that is being copied? Is the system using a database to store data and, if so, is it external to the instance? Also, to confirm -- you are using Linux, right? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Thanks. I have edited the question.

Comment: What information is changing on Primary aside from what is stored in the database? Normally, a server is configured at startup and its contents should not change aside from temp files and code releases. Since you have a secondary server up and running, why are you not currently load balancing between them, sending traffic to both instances?

Comment: aside from database, we deploy code almost every 2 weeks. we also store user uplaoded files (which will be moved to s3 bucket). I can use secondary for load balancing, but for now lets say I just want to use secondary in case of failover only.

Comment: To use it for load balancing, I will have to first figure out an easy way to keep both servers in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional High-Availability design is:

- Data stored in **Amazon RDS**, preferably configured as Multi-AZ in case of failure
- Objects stored in **Amazon S3**
- At least two **Amazon EC2 instances** for the application, spread across more than one Availability Zone — preferably created with Auto Scaling
- A **Load Balancer** in front of the instances
- An **Amazon Route 53** domain name resolving to the Load Balancer

[image: High-Availability architecture]

This way, both instances are serving traffic (you can use two smaller instances if you wish). The Load Balancer performs continuous health checks. If an instance fails the health check, the load balancer stops sending it traffic, so users are minimally impacted.

If Auto Scaling is configured, it can automatically replace an unhealthy instance. This can be done by providing a fully-configured AMI, or by providing a User Data script that installs and configures the software at startup (or a combination of both).

When performing a software update:

- Update the Auto Scaling *Launch Configuration*, which defines how new instances should start (eg different User Data or AMI)
- Tell Auto Scaling to launch a new instance, then terminate an old instance — this is a rolling update
- If you can't do a rolling update (due to code change), deploy a second Auto Scaling group and test it. If everything is okay, point the Load Balancer to the new Auto Scaling group, then terminate the old one (after a few minutes to allow connection draining).

This is very similar to what Elastic Beanstalk offers — it will create the Load Balancer and Auto Scaling group for you, and deploy code updates.

The result is a highly-available, resilient architecture that can auto-recover from failure. It will also force you to use code repositories rather than manually updating servers, which leads to greater reliability and reproducibility.

See: [AWS Design for Web Application Hosting](https://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf)